# react native-redux getting error when handling multiple data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

I am using react native-redux to set global state and it works fine when handling single data but when I have multiple data its not working. Below is my code:

```
 import {connect} from 'react-redux'

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        comment:'',
        region:[],
        }
    }

      <Button
                  onPress={() => {
                           this.setState({
                             comment : this.state.comment,
                             // works fine if I only handle comment or region
                             region  : this.state.region,
                             },
                           () => this.props.commentHandler(this.state),
                           () => this.props.regionHandler(this.state)}}>
                                  <Text>UPDATE</Text>
       </Button>
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            comment : state.comment,
            region  : state.region
        }
    }

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            commentHandler : (state) => dispatch({ type: 'COMMENT', payload: state.comment}),
            regionHandler  : (state) => dispatch({ type: 'REGION', payload: state.region})

        }
    }
```

I don't know what I did wrong but when I try to handle multiple data for example, comment & region it won't work. It works perfectly if I remove  `() => this.props.commentHandler(this.state)` or `() => this.props.regionHandler(this.state)` but doesn't work together.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Any comments or advise would be really appreciated!

Comment: since you are using the callback of setState, i would suggest to wrap your handlers into one functionbody like this https://jsfiddle.net/1eg8L7j3/ instead of calling them after each other.

Comment: @Paulquappe thanks for the comments it works if I wrap my handlers into one fucntionbody, however, when I try to call the state i.e `this.props.region`, `this.props.comment` in the next screen, it will only display the first state which is `this.props.comment` the other one will be undefined any idea why?

Comment: sorry no, i need to see source code.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping my handlers into one function made it work. Thanks to @Paulquappe.

```
  <Button
              onPress={() => {
                       this.setState({
                         comment : this.state.comment,
                         region  : this.state.region,
                         },
                       () => this.props.regionHandler(this.state),this.props.commentHandler(this.state),
                       () => console.log(this.props.comment,'this.props.comment?'),
                       () => console.log(this.props.region,'this.props.region?'))
                     }}>
```